# Looking for eval() alternative when node/attribute name is variable/parameter

Tags: javascript, eval

It is clear that when the attribute (for example ***id***) exists/is defined in the script, we should use `obj[id]` and not `eval('obj.' + id)`. However, I have not yet found a solution for the case where the attribute name is itself a variable and not defined - for example when recieved as a parameter. In my case I have node.js on the server recieving a JSON object ***requestData*** being sent from the client via socket.io. The ***requestData*** contains a key/value pair: ***requestData.key*** is an array of the node names that make up the JSON path to the element, and ***requestData.val*** is the value to be stored in that element.

In the server script there is a defined JSON object called ***root*** which contains information relevant to the app, for example:

```
"root": {
  "pages": {
    "TM1010": {
      "appId": "TM1010",
      "componentName": "UserTasksPage"
    },
    "TM1020": {
      "appId": "TM1020",
      "componentName": "UsersPage"
    }
  }
}
```

If the client were to send a request to update an element - for example to change the value of ***root.pages.TM1010.componentName*** - this is how it would be sent from the client:

```
let requestData = {'key': ['pages', 'TM1010', 'componentName'], 'val': newComponentName};
this.socket.emit('changeData', requestData);
```

And this is how it is recieved and executed on the server:

```
socket.on('changeData', (requestData) => {
  var str = 'root'
  var key = requestData.key
  var len = key.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   str = str + '["' + key[i] + '"]'
  }
  str = str + '=requestData.val'
  eval(str)
});
```

So that what is being executed in the end (the value of ***str***) is:

```
root["pages"]["TM1010"]["componentName"]=requestData.val
```

**How could this be done without `eval()` ?**

As I mentioned, I do not know the names of those elements that will be sent from the client. All I have on the server is one JSON object called 'root' and I want to continuously add/update to it as I recieve data from the client.
I have tried solutions based on JEXL or mathjs but it doesn't seem to work for this type of case.

Comment: What's wrong with just accessing `root` directly (at first step, smth like `var target = root`), then going through the given path in `for` loop (like `target = target[key[i]]`)? In the end you can just assign to target, like `target = requestData.val`. Auto-vivification might be of concern, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the keys by taking the object and assign the value with the last key.

```js
const
    setValue = (object, keys, value) => {
        var path = keys.slice(),
            last = path.pop();
        path.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object)[last] = value;
    };

var data = { root: { pages: { TM1010: { appId: "TM1010", componentName: "UserTasksPage" }, TM1020: { appId: "TM1020", componentName: "UsersPage" } } } },
    requestData = { key: ['pages', 'TM1010', 'componentName'], val: 'newComponentName' };

setValue(data.root, requestData.key, requestData.val);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```